# Whitespaces from my keyboard not interpreted in markdown titles

Tags: keyboard, markdown

The spaces I type with my keyboard are not recognized in my markdown titles in (at least) atom syntax highlighting and some online markdown editors such as commonmark ([see example](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%23%20Try%20CommonMark%0A%0A%0A%23%23%20Title%20with%20space%20c%2Fc%20from%20above%0A%0A%23%23%C2%A0Title%20with%20from%20keyboard%0A)):

I run on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored a bit my keyboard settings and noticed that my keyboard was configured in `French (legacy, alternative)`.

[image: screenshot from 2017-08-03 15-02-26]

Although I'm pretty sure this settings was applied by the automatic keyboard layout detection from ubuntu at computer first boot, the term `legacy` didn't sound right to me. So I just shifted the settings to `French` and voilà... it just works now.

I guess the keyboard set with `French (legacy, alternative)` layout mapped the space key to some alternative charater unrecognized by some markdown editors...